# Django - crispy form not showing

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to render this form:

```
class LoadForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Load

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                'whouse',
                'supplier',
                'company',
                'product',
                'quantity',
                'unit_price',
                'load_date',
            )
        )
```

with the following view:

```
def load(request):
    form = LoadForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'title': 'Nuovo Carico',
    }

    return render(request, 'warehouse/load.html', context)
```

and the following template:

```
{% extends "masterpage.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block headTitle %}
<title>{{title}}</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block contentHead %}
{% endblock %}

{% block contentBody %}
{% load document_tags %}
{% load custom_tags %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<FORM method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    {{ form.media }}
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="alert alert-info">
        {{ title }}
    </div>
    {% crispy form %}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary margin-left" value="CARICA">


</FORM>

{% endblock %}
```

For some strange reason the form will not show up, I just see the title and the input button. I've tried the very simple form.as_p with no crispy, but still nothing...

By looking at the sourse code on the browser I see there is a div with class 'form-row' but not form in it...

looks strange.

Any help?

thank you very much.

Carlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form class is defined as follows: `class LoadForm(forms.Form):` Note that here this is a `Form` and not a `ModelForm` hence using a `Meta` class and specifying `model` makes no difference. Instead you want to use a [`ModelForm` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) and you also need to specify either `fields` or `exclude` in the `Meta`:

```
class LoadForm(forms.ModelForm): # `ModelForm` here
    class Meta:
        model = Load
        fields = '__all__' # All fields
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                'whouse',
                'supplier',
                'company',
                'product',
                'quantity',
                'unit_price',
                'load_date',
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Call form in template like this. First the name of the form you have in context plus pipe crispy. It works for me.

```
</div>
{{form|crispy}}
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary margin-left" value="CARICA">
```